# How to define format for both Y and List[X] in Play JSON when X extends from Y and Y is trait?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I can't convert list in specific case: when type is extends from trait.

When I can convert:

```scala
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
  import play.api.libs.json._
  sealed trait Item
  case class Id(id: Long) extends Item
  case class MyList(list: List[Id])
  object MyFormat {
    implicit lazy val idFormat = Json.format[Id]
    implicit lazy val myListFormat = Json.format[MyList]
  }
```

When I can not convert:

```scala
  sealed trait Item
  case class Id(id: Long) extends Item
  case class MyList(list: List[Id])
  object MyFormat {
    implicit lazy val itemFormat = new Format[Item] {
      override def writes(o: Item): JsValue = o match {
        case i: Id => idFormat.writes(i)
      }
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Item] = {
        idFormat.reads(json)
      }
    }
    implicit lazy val idFormat = Json.format[Id]
    implicit lazy val myListFormat = Json.format[MyList]
  }
```

Error:
`Error:(33, 49) No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for scala.collection.immutable.List[Main2.Id] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
    implicit lazy val myListFormat = Json.format[MyList]`

Why I can't format in 2nd case?

If I add formatter for list:

```scala
implicit lazy val idsFormat = Json.format[List[Id]]
```

then I got `Error:(33, 46) No instance of Reads is available for scala.collection.immutable.Nil in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
    implicit lazy val idsFormat = Json.format[List[Id]]`

PS:
The only one solution than I found:

1. Define custom format for `List[Id]`
2. When read or write, use format for `Id`
3. When read, use

```
def flatten[T](xs: Seq[JsResult[T]]): JsResult[List[T]] = {
  val (ss: Seq[JsSuccess[T]], fs: Seq[JsError]) = xs.partition(_.isSuccess)
  if (fs.isEmpty) JsSuccess(ss.map(_.get).toList) else fs.head
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If play JSON features automatic/semiautomatic codec instances derivation, then it will use implicit to enable such a mechanism. It means that codecs for complex things should be introduced *after* their components.

In your case, it seems like play JSON tries to derive codec for List as for case class ,i. e. as for `List(a1, List(a2, ..., List(an, Nil)))` and when it hits Nil, it doesn't know how to derive codec for that.

I believe you want your list encoded not like a chain of folded objects but as JSON array.

Then you should search play sources for default `List[T]` codec and try to use it by specializing it for `Id`.

General tool for debugging missing implicits is compiler option "-Xlog-implicits". It will log all failed implicit searches to console, and it is possible to figure out what's missing by these messages.

It is also strongly advised to know [how](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) implicit works before working with libraries that use this feautre extensively.

And last, but not least:

Have you ever tried using [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/)? It [features](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html) automatic and semi-automatic JSON derivation for families of sealed traits and standard scala classes. It even has [integration](https://github.com/jilen/play-circe) with play framework. Circe derivation removes the most headache of writing codec code, but requires strong knowledge of implicit precedence to work properly. The way it works described [here](http://enear.github.io/2016/09/27/bits-of-shapeless-1/) and [here](http://enear.github.io/2016/09/27/bits-of-shapeless-2/).

You can also try to create your own derivation for play-json if there's no adequate standard one with [morphling](https://github.com/danslapman/morphling).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later